# Dota2 - is it possible to get private match info via API into sql database?

Tags: sql, api

I would like to start a little hobby project. Which is the best way and where to start to accomplish the following:

Me and my friend plays dota2 sometime, usually bot mach against each other. So I would like to get results, who won the mach and save this info into sql database for example.

Is it possible to get this information via dota 2 API and how to get it into my database?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PHP page to get API results from 
https://api.opendota.com/api/players/{account_id}/matches

Loop through answers (the result will be in JSON format, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php for help), save new maches in your db.